# C# ASPX Set h1 background color runtime

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to change the background color of my h1 header line on my webpage at runtime. If we are running in prod/dev I want the background color of the H1 header tag set accordingly.

I currently am setting the background color for h1 as follows:

```
 align="center" style="background-color: #389BD6 ">HEADER 1 LINE
```

But I want to be able to specify the color differently depending on the current environment.

I am assuming it will involve a css, but that is new to me and need some help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you use to define the environment? IE how will the stylesheet know which environment you are in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS: Just What The Doctor Ordered**

CSS as you mentioned is the proper course of action to handle this, you could simply define a style that would target your `h1` elements as expected :

```
<style type='text/css'>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #389BD6;
    }
</style>
```

You could explicitly reference this in your HTML itself (preferably in the `<head>` section) or via an external CSS file (also defined in the `<head>` section of your page) :

```
<!-- A reference to a CSS file containing the previous style -->
<link href="your-css-file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Styling Based on Environment**

With regards to changing the style based on your environment, you could consider adding a CSS class to a high-level element of your page at run-time and adding another style to override the previous default one :

```
<!-- Define a runat="server" tag on your body element and an ID (assumes Web Forms) -->
<body id="body" runat="server">
```

and then within your `Page_Load` event, set the class based on your environment (i.e. Debug, Production, etc.) :

```
// Find your body element
var body = FindControl("body") as HtmlGenericControl;
// If you were able to find it, set it's class
if(body != null)
{
     // Set your environment here
     body.Attributes["class"] = "production";
}
```

This will render the "production" class on your `<body>` element :

```
<body id="body" class="production">
```

which you can use to define another CSS style to target only `<h1>` elements in the production environment :

```
<style type='text/css'>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #389BD6;
    }
    /* Target <h1> elements in production */
    .production h1 {
        background-color: purple;
    }
</style>
```

You could also accomplish this by building multiple stylesheets (i.e. `production.css`, `development.css`, etc.) and defining each of your specific styles in there and using some mechanism like [Preprocessor Directives](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=preprocessor%20directives%20c%23) to determine which to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be dynamic, you could do something like:

```
<link href="http://somewebsite.com/css.aspx" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This way you have an aspx file that is treated like a css file, but you can dynamically set the value of h1 background colour for example, by using whatever logic you wish in the .aspx
But only use this stylesheet to contain style that may change at runtime, as it creates a lot of overhead.